# DD-WRT - Unable to remove a file using script

Tags: linux, bash, router, script, dd-wrt

Currenlty runing Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r30600M kongac (09/09/16)

I'm having issues with the `rm` command.  I can use the command without issue on the CLI but it's not working correctly when run from within the script.  I have included a snippet below.

```
#!/bin/sh
BASE=$(basename $0)
NAME=${BASE%\.*}
TMP=/jffs/tmp/$NAME
PID=$TMP/chase.pid
rm "$PID"
```

When the script is run I get "rm: can't remove '/jffs/tmp//chase.pid': No such file or directory" error.  I have tried running the script with only the code posted above and I still receive the same error.  The file exists but I'm unable to delete it.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: What does `ls -l "$PID"` show?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             5 Sep 22 15:03 /jffs/tmp/chase/chase.pid`

Comment: The file named in your `ls` listing is in a different directory from the file named in the `can't remove` error message.

Comment: Both of the `rm` and `ls` commands point to the same variable.  The `"$PID"` variable holds the value of `/jffs/tmp/chase/chase.pid`.